# Issue Switching between Popups & Main Window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

On main window, I am trying to click on a link which opens a popup window. I get text from that window and then close it.
Again I repeat this for about 40 links on the main window.

But, after a loop of 3-4 times, it is failing. Not sure why it is happening. Mostly it is happening at 'if' condition doesn't meet, but it may happen otherwise also.

I get following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
for(int x=1;x<119;x+=3)
{
    //waitforelement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr["+x+"]/td[2]/a")));

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr["+x+"]/td[2]/a"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Set <String> windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator <String> iterat = windowids.iterator();

    String mainwindowid = iterat.next();
    String next1stwindowid = iterat.next();

    driver.switchTo().window(next1stwindowid);
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    Thread.sleep(750);
    if(!pageSource.contains("Resume is no longer available."))                  
    {
        String Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/span[1]")).getText();
        String Phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")).getText();
        String Email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td")).getText();
        System.out.println("On page "+i+", the detail for list number "+x + "\t candidate is: " +Name +"\t"+ Phone+"\t"+Email);                         
    }

    Thread.sleep(750);
    driver.close();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.switchTo().window(mainwindowid);                                             
}
```

Comment: Once again we are met with a possible problem of the usage in Thread.sleep(); Can you try doing running this using Explicit Waits to see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

As @aimbire suggested in the comments you should avoid using `Thread.Sleep` as much as possible. Instead I would recommend using the [WebDriverWait class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html). With this you can set a *maximum* timeout and a condition (eg. does the page contain your text). Using a sleep means that if the Server does not achieve actions in the same amount of time each iteration of your test, then inconsistencies such as those you are facing can occur.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persist using normal selenium wait,try using fluent wait.